# Dynamic arrays inside a class

Tags: c++, class, matrix, dynamic-arrays

I am doing the following exercise at the moment:

A generic Matrix class (15 pt)

> a) Create a class called Matrix, it should contain storage for M*N
>   numbers of type double. Just like earlier, when choosing how to store
>   your data it is often useful to know what we are going to use the data
>   for later. In matrix operations we are going to access the diﬀerent
>   elements of the matrix based on their column and/or row, therefore it
>   is useful to order the members of Matrix as an array. Also, we are
>   going to need to change the size of the data stored in the matrix,
>   therefore it should be dynamically allocated.
>
> b) Create constructors for the matrix.
>
> Create the following three constructors: Matrix() • Default
>   constructor, should initialize the matrix into the invalid state.
>
> explicit Matrix(unsigned int N) • Should construct a valid NxN Matrix,
>   initialized as an identity matrix. (The explicit keyword is not in the
>   syllabus, but it should be used here.)
>
> Matrix(unsigned int M, unsigned int N) • Should construct a valid MxN
>   Matrix, initialized as a Zero matrix. (All elements are zero.)
>
> ~Matrix() • The destructor of Matrix, should delete any dynamically
>   allocated memory.

My class this far is as follows:

```
    class Matrix{
    private:
        int rows;
        int columns;
        double* matrix;
    public:
        Matrix();
        explicit Matrix(int N);
        Matrix(int M, int N);
        ~Matrix();
};
```

And the rest of my code:

```
    Matrix::Matrix(){
    double * matrix = NULL;
}

Matrix::Matrix(int N){
    double * matrix = new double[N * N];
    this->rows = N;
    this->columns = N;

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            if(i==j)
                matrix[i * N + j] = 1;
            else
                matrix[i * N + j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(int M, int N){
    double * matrix = new double[M * N];
    this->rows = M;
    this->columns = N;

    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            matrix[i * N + j] =  0;
    }
}

Matrix::~Matrix(){
    delete [] matrix;
}
```

Have I created the dynamic array and the constructors correctly?
I am later in the exercise to create three different arrays using the three different constructors. How do I do this correclty? If i try something like this

```
Matrix::Matrix();
Matrix::Matrix(3);
```

or

```
Matrix::Matrix(3,4)
```

i get the following error:

> Unhandeled exception at 0x773c15de in Øving_6.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xccccccc0.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your constructors, you're defining a local variable

```
double * matrix = new double[N * N];
```

which shadows your member variable of the same name, so the member is never initialised.

All you should need is to change it to

```
matrix = new double[N * N];
```

And it's very un-C++ to use `this->` for member access unless it's absolutely necessary for disambiguation (which is almost never)

Answer (score 2):

You will find more "C++" (and sometime the only way to initialize members):

```
Matrix::Matrix(int M, int N):   rows    (M), 
                                columns (N), 
                                matrix  (new double[M * N]) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            matrix[i * N + j] =  0;

}
```

Now try to understand this:

```
Matrix::Matrix(       int N):   rows    (N), 
                                columns (N), 
                                matrix  (new double[N * N]) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            matrix[i * N + j] =  (i==j);

}
```

If you use:

```
class Matrix{
private:
    int rows;
    int columns;
    std::unique_ptr<double[]> matrix;
```

you will find that you dont need a destructor, and some other inerest thing. Also, read my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your three constructors, you are masking the instance variable matrix with a local one. Try this:

```
Matrix::Matrix(){
 this->matrix = NULL;
}

Matrix::Matrix(int N){
 this->matrix = new double[N * N];
 this->rows = N;
this->columns = N;

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
        if(i==j)
            matrix[i * N + j] = 1;
        else
            matrix[i * N + j] = 0;
    }
}
}

Matrix::Matrix(int M, int N){
 this->matrix = new double[M * N];
this->rows = M;
this->columns = N;

for(int i = 0; i < M; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        matrix[i * N + j] =  0;
}
```

}